# Use C++ managed Form from unmanaged C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

please I need your help, I googled a lot and any answer for this problem....

I have a solution that includes various Unmanaged C++ projects, but now I need to use a Visual C++ Form (that is Managed) into the main unmanaged project, and comunicate with it.
It's possible to do it? via wrapper, dll.... how?

I googled a lot but all the cases I found talk about how use Unmanaged into Managed, or are incomplete examples. I found this example and seems that it works, but doesn't compile.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9903/Calling-Managed-Code-from-Unmanaged-Code-and-vice

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Bolting a GUI on top of a native program that wasn't designed for it never comes to a good end.  The only winning strategy is to do it the other way around.  Let your EXE be a managed program, using C++/CLI to interop with your existing code, rebuilt as a static library or a DLL.

Comment: I agree, but It's not possible to let the program be managed, but I found a solution, I'm going to post it

Comment: Why you voted negative? Any better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution...

1 - When I want to have the FORM control into non managed code (for create, show, hide, set controls value...) I exported static methods as `__declspec(dllexport)`

2 - When I want to send info from FORM to non managed code I do it using callbacks.

I'm going to explain it....

Firstly... I create a CLR project as DLL, create a windows Form (MyForm.h) with some controls:

- 1 exit button
- 1 button that SEND info TO NON MANAGED code
- and 1 checkbox that RECEIVE new status FROM NON MANAGED code

(I ommit the gode generated by visual studio)

```
namespace TestUnmanaged {
... code ommitted ...
    private: System::Void QuitBtn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 this->Close();
             }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
//Call to non managed function!!!!
                 CallToCallBack();
             }
    };
}
```

Then, I create a static (non managed) class that has a pointer to the form, and manage it's creation, etc..

```
//Type of my specific callback function
typedef std::function<bool (int& _msg)> T_CALLBACK_FUNC;

public class unmanagedClass
{
public: 

    unmanagedClass();
    ~unmanagedClass();

    void CreateForm( void );

    HWND getFormHandle(void) const;
    void setCallbackFunction(T_CALLBACK_FUNC _callbackFuntion);
    void callToCallbackFunction(int _value);
    //public for fast tests
    gcroot<TestUnmanaged::MyForm^> p;
private:
    HWND m_hWnd;
    T_CALLBACK_FUNC m_funcionCallback;
};

unmanagedClass s_unmanaged;
```

Here's the .cpp implementation...

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//          Static Functions for DLL_EXPORT
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void CloseForm( void )
{   
    Application::Exit();
}

void CallToCallBack( void )
{
    int valor = 5;
    s_unmanaged.callToCallbackFunction(valor);
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//          Methods for Unmanaged Class
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
HWND unmanagedClass::getFormHandle( void ) const
{
    return m_hWnd;
}

unmanagedClass::unmanagedClass()
{
    p = gcnew(TestUnmanaged::MyForm);
}

unmanagedClass::~unmanagedClass()
{
    delete (p);
}

void unmanagedClass::CreateForm( void )
{
    Application::Run(p);    
}

void unmanagedClass::setCallbackFunction( T_CALLBACK_FUNC _callbackFuntion )
{
    m_funcionCallback = _callbackFuntion;
}

void unmanagedClass::callToCallbackFunction( int _value )
{
    m_funcionCallback(_value);
}
```

Now, I create all the static functions that will be exported as dllexport:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void CreateFormDLL(void)
{
    s_unmanaged.CreateForm();
}

__declspec(dllexport) void CloseFormDLL(void)
{
    s_unmanaged.p->Close();
}

__declspec(dllexport) void ShowFormDLL(void)
{
    s_unmanaged.p->Show();  
}

__declspec(dllexport) void HideFormDLL(void)
{
    s_unmanaged.p->Hide();
}

__declspec (dllexport) void setCallbackFunctionDLL( T_CALLBACK_FUNC& _doFunction)
{
    s_unmanaged.setCallbackFunction(_doFunction);
}

__declspec (dllexport) void setCheckBoxDLL( bool _newValue )
{
    s_unmanaged.p->getCam01ChkBox()->Checked = _newValue;
}

__declspec (dllexport) HWND getFormHandleDLL( void )
{
    return (HWND)s_unmanaged.p->Handle.ToPointer();
}
```

Now.... I create the Win32 console App project and link the Managed project. This will be the main process, and the class "ManagedWrapper". Here is the source....

```
class ManagedWrapper
{
public:
    ManagedWrapper(void);
    ~ManagedWrapper(void);

    void init(void);

    void createForm(void);
    void showForm(void);
    void closeForm(void);
    void setCam01ChkBox(const bool _newValue);
private:
    void createFormThread(void);

    static bool callBackReceiver(int a);
};


#include "ManagedWrapper.h"
#include <thread>

__declspec(dllimport) void CreateFormDLL(void);
__declspec(dllimport) void CloseFormDLL(void);
__declspec(dllimport) void ShowFormDLL(void);
__declspec(dllimport) void HideFormDLL(void);
typedef std::function<bool (int& _msg)> T_CALLBACK_FUNC;
__declspec (dllimport) void setCallbackFunctionDLL( T_CALLBACK_FUNC& _doFunction);
__declspec (dllimport) void setCheckBoxDLL( bool _newValue );

ManagedWrapper::ManagedWrapper(void)
{
}

ManagedWrapper::~ManagedWrapper(void)
{
}

void ManagedWrapper::createForm( void )
{
    std::thread showThread (&ManagedWrapper::createFormThread, this);
    showThread.detach();
}

void ManagedWrapper::createFormThread( void )
{
    CreateFormDLL();
}

void ManagedWrapper::closeForm( void )
{
    CloseFormDLL();
}

void ManagedWrapper::showForm( void )
{
    ShowFormDLL();
}

void ManagedWrapper::init( void )
{
    setCallbackFunctionDLL(T_CALLBACK_FUNC(&ManagedWrapper::callBackReceiver));
}

bool ManagedWrapper::callBackReceiver( int a )
{
    printf("Hello world. Parameter value = %d\n",a);
    return true;
}

void ManagedWrapper::setCam01ChkBox( const bool _newValue )
{
    setCheckBoxDLL( _newValue );
}
```

And finally.... the simplest use from the `main()`, create the Form, set the checkbox values, if the user click on the button the callback function writes on console... and finally close.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ManagedWrapper umWrap;
    umWrap.init();
    umWrap.createForm();
    system("PAUSE");
    umWrap.setCam01ChkBox(true);
    system("PAUSE");
    umWrap.setCam01ChkBox(false);
    system("PAUSE");
    umWrap.closeForm();
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the long answer, but I believe that may be usefull for somebody.